# Can a plain HTML link (A) reload a page without query string values

Tags: html

I want to essentially reload the page I'm on without some of the query strings which might be present (thus changing content on the page). I've found that leaving the href tag empty like so `href=""` works, but I wonder if this a safe method, ie. does it work in older browsers?

**Edit:**

In fact scrap that, leaving it blank doesn't work (some great testing by me there). So, I guess my question now is, how can I reload the same page without any query string values? And without knowing the file name and without using Javascript. I guess I'm looking for something like `/` or `#`.

Comment: "And without knowing the file name and without using Javascript" basically means you can't do this unless you put a link somewhere on the page that already contains the full path, minus the querystring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I know a trick. When you use a `<form>` tag with empty `action` and no (or GET) `method` parameter it will use your url but will replace the GET parameters (query string) with the values in your form, so:

On page `http://example.com/foo.html?query=string`

```
<form action="">
    <input type="submit" value="hello" />
</form>
```

If you click on the button you will get to:

- `http://example.com/foo.html` (Firefox 8)
- `http://example.com/foo.html` (Internet Explorer 9)
- `http://example.com/foo.html?` (Chrome 15)
- `http://example.com/foo.html?` (Safari 5)

**Edit:** the trailing question mark is likely a Webkit issue.

Comment: Ah, while I am not tempted to use your entire solution (the form), one thing does work for me. Passing through just a question mark in the `href` attribute will successfully remove all query string values AND cause a page reload, albeit my URL now has a question mark at the end, which I can live with for my scenario. My final code looks like so: `<a href="?">Sales</a>`

Comment: href="?" is what I suggested, too. IMHO it's the easiest to use.

Answer (score 6):

There is [an interesting post about empty URLs](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/16/empty-string-urls-in-html-a-followup/). It refers to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), which defines URLs.

Basically, from a *spec* point of view you should be save, in that `href=""` references the current page.

I assume that all browsers adhere to this, but this is just an educated guess. [The HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/urls.html#urls) also allows empty URLs.

*Edit:* To meet the updated question, (almost) removing the query string can be done with `href="?"`.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. While it does reload the page, unfortunately it does not clear any query string values (apologies, I have since changed my question to reflect this, bad testing on my part)

Answer (score 0):

Empty href is an empty relative uri which should be resolved to base uri without problems.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, you can try this: `href="#"`.

Comment: `#` does not reload the page if there is no change to either 1) the file name or 2) the query string.